# How to reflection check nullable object is IDictionary

Tags: c#, reflection

How to reflection check nullable object is IDictionary

e.g :

if object is not null it can use `is` keyword to check.

```
void Main()
{
    Dictionary<string, object> v = new Dictionary<string,object>();
    Console.WriteLine(CheckValueIsIDictionary(v)); //true
}

bool CheckValueIsIDictionary(object value){
    return value is IDictionary;
}
```

but if parameter value is null then will get `false`

```
void Main()
{
    Dictionary<string, object> v = null;
    Console.WriteLine(CheckValueIsIDictionary(v)); //false
}

bool CheckValueIsIDictionary(object value){
    return value is IDictionary;
}
```

I expect get `true` result, thanks!

---

update:

I want to check value declare type is a IDictionary

before example you can know this null value is from `Dictionary<string,object>` and this type is a `IDictionary` and I want to get the relationship result.

and why I'd like to do it :

I want to check values is IDictionary or not to do different logic, object value can be Array or Dictionary<int,int> or List

Comment: You might have a misunderstanding here. `null` _can't_ be an instance of `IDictionary`, precisely because it is `null`. Do you mean to check whether the variable `v` passed in is of type `IDictionary`? If so, this might be an XY problem. Can you explain why would you want to do this, and what would you do with the fact that the variable passed in is of type `IDictionary`?

Comment: @Sweeper I want to check value declared type is a IDictionary

Comment: You can only do this with generics and type inference, but even that depends on you having a variable that is declared as the type.

Comment: That's quite a weird thing to do, so I suspect this is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: This really needs an explanation of _why_ you want to do this, because it doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: @Llama I want to check values is IDictionary or not to do different logic, object value can be Array or Dictionary<int,int> or List

Comment: If a value is `null`, then it can't be an `IDictionary`.

Comment: @Llama yes, it looks like no way to do it.

Comment: I've provided an answer which gets close, but with a big caveat.

Comment: It sounds like you are putting an array, list, or dictionary into an variable of type `object`, but that can be null. The thing is, you can't differentiate, at runtime, whether a `null` is a null dictionary or a null array or a null list. They are all the same `null`.

Comment: @Sweeper yes, I want to do something like jsonconvert serializeobject action

Comment: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` is nothing like what you are doing here. It serialises non-null dictionaries to JSON dictionaries, non-null arrays and lists to JSON arrays, and `null` to JSON `null`. It does not do different things depending on whether it's a null _list_ or a null _dictionary_. They are indistinguishable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only do this with type inference and generics:

```
public static bool CheckValueIsIDictionary<T>(T value)
{
    Type typeT = typeof(T);
    return value is IDictionary || typeof(IDictionary).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T));
}
```

Obviously if you have something like this, you'll get `false`:

```
Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = null;
object o = myDictionary;
Console.WriteLine(CheckValueIsIDictionary(o));
```

But it will work where there is a value, or where the type is known at compile time.